# Type hinting a method that returns a string or error in Python 3.7+

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, pytype

I have a Python script that starts with a method searching for a CSV file in the current directory or downloads a directory to make some processing. If no CSV file is found, the program should not run and exit with an error message.

I type annotated a tentative method as follows:

```
import glob
import os


def get_csv_filename() -> str:
    """ Returns first csv filename in current folder or Downloads folder """
    csv_filenames = glob.glob('*.csv')
    if csv_filenames:
        return csv_filenames[0]
    home = os.path.expanduser("~")
    csv_filenames = glob.glob(home + "/Downloads/*.csv")
    if csv_filenames:
        return csv_filenames[0]
    # If I don't use return, I also get problems with pylint
    return exit("Error: no file found, check the documentation for more info.")


def main() -> None:
    """ Reads a CSV and does some processing """
    filename = get_csv_filename()
```

If I type check with eg. pytype I get the error:

```
get_csv_filename: bad option in return type [bad-return-type]
  Expected: str
  Actually returned: None
```

What would you recommend doing to make this code compliant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the ideas of [Steve Bremer's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59547673/type-hinting-a-method-that-returns-a-string-or-error-in-python-3-7/59549492#59549492), the problem can be solved with a simpler approach:

```
from typing import Optional
def get_csv_filename() -> Optional[str]:
    ...
```

In fact, `Optional[something]` is equivalent to `Union[None, something]`.

Answer (score 2):

[This section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-noreturn-type) of PEP 484 may be helpful. I don't have *mypy* or *pytype* installed to try it, but maybe this would work:

```
from typing import NoReturn

def get_csv_filename() -> str:
    """ Returns first csv filename in current folder or Downloads folder """
    csv_filenames = glob.glob('*.csv')
    if csv_filenames:
        return csv_filenames[0]
    ...
    stop("Error: no file found, check the documentation for more info.")
    return ""

def stop(msg) -> NoReturn:
    exit(msg)
```

Another option would be:

```
from typing import Union

def get_csv_filename() -> Union[None, str]:
...
```